# Allocate (spread) array to each two values will different

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need allocate (spread/ take round) array to each two values will different

For example

```
array('cat','cat','cat','cat','dog','cat','cat','apple','mouse')
```

I need get something like

```
array('cat','dog','cat','apple','cat','mouse','cat','cat','cat')
```

and if last elements is same = I have three 'cat' in the end of array I need remove it and extract it in other array.

And need delete elements as little as possible.

Which is the best way to do it in PHP? Thanks.

This array can be have any values. Any count of values. There is more than one repeating word: five times 'cat', ten times 'dog', two times 'la-la-la' and so on.
I need allocate it to

```
elem1 != elem2
elem3 != elem4
elem5 != elem6
elem7 != elem8
```

If will left values and I can't allocate it this way I need remove it and show this values (to I see how much and which values left).

My solution with [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) PHP-function:

```
$source = array('cat','cat','cat','cat','dog','cat','cat','cat','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','mouse');
while ( !empty( $source ) ){
    while ($source[ 0 ] == $source[ 1 ]) {
        shuffle( $source ); // it's ruefully
        $arr_contains_same_value = false;
        for($i=1; $i<count($source);$i++) {
            if ($source[0] != $source[$i]){
                $arr_contains_same_value = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($arr_contains_same_value == false){ break 2; }
    }
    if (count($source) == 1) break ;
    print $source[0]."\n";
    print $source[1]."\n";
    unset( $source[ 0 ], $source[ 1 ] ); 
    $source = array_values($source);
}
print "Was left:";
var_dump($source);
```

**And for two-dimensional array:**

```
$source = array(
array("help people", "cat"),
array("force", "tiger"),
array("Tom", "cat"),
array("black", "cat"),
array("Jerry", "mouse"),
array("UNIX", "cat"),
array("young", "lion"),
array("angry", "dog"),
array("kind", "dog")
);
while ( !empty( $source ) ){
    while ($source[ 0 ][1] == $source[ 1 ][1]) {
        shuffle( $source ); // it's ruefully
        $arr_contains_same_value = false;
        for($i=1; $i<count($source);$i++) {
            if ($source[0][1] != $source[$i][1]){
                $arr_contains_same_value = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($arr_contains_same_value == false){ break 2; }
    }
    if (count($source) == 1) break;
    print $source[0][1]."\n";
    print $source[1][1]."\n";
    unset( $source[ 0 ], $source[ 1 ] ); 
    $source = array_values($source);
}
print "Was left:\n\n";
var_dump($source);
```

Comment: What have you tryed so far? Showing us your research help everyone

Comment: What happens if there is more than one repeating word, for example: `array('cat','cat','cat','cat','dog','dog','dog','cat','cat','apple','mouse');`?  Is this a valid scenario?

Comment: Thanks. See above. Yes, there is more than one repeating word.

Comment: Lets we make some clear expressions for what do you want. You want to make Sandwich from your array's elements. The Sandwich has two main parts, bread and food. In your case bread is `Cat` while other elements are the Sandwich's food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to solve your problem,
In this function at the first time check count of values to sort items in optimal way for sorting.

```
$items = array('cat','cat','cat','cat','cat','apple', 'dog', 'dog','cat','cat','apple','mouse');

function mySort($items){
    $map = array_count_values($items);
    arsort($map);
    $result = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++) { 

        foreach ($map as $key => $value) {
            //print_r($result);
            if($value <= 0 || $key == end($result)) continue;
            $result[] = $key;
            if(--$map[$key] <= 0) unset($map[$key]);
            break;
        }
        arsort($map);
    }

    if(!empty($map)) 
        $result = array_merge($result, array_fill(0, end($map), key($map)));

    return $result;
}

print_r(mySort($items));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => cat
    [1] => apple
    [2] => cat
    [3] => dog
    [4] => cat
    [5] => apple
    [6] => cat
    [7] => mouse
    [8] => cat
    [9] => dog
    [10] => cat
    [11] => cat
)
```

And for tow-dimensional array you can use this function:

```
function myarsort(&$items){
  uasort($items, function($a, $b){
    return (count($a) > count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
  });
}

function mySort2($items){
    $map = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $map[$item[1]][] = $item;
    }
    myarsort($map);
    $result = array();

    for ($i=0; $i < count($items); $i++) { 
        foreach ($map as $key => $value) {
            if(isset(end($result)[1]) && $key == end($result)[1]) continue;
            $result[] = end($value);
            unset($map[$key][count($value)-1]);
            if(count($map[$key]) == 0) unset($map[$key]);
            break;
        }
        myarsort($map);
    }
    if(!empty($map)) 
        $result = array_merge($result, end($map));

    return $result;
}

print_r(mySort2($items2));
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks. And I added my half-working solution. But your solution works.

Comment: Hello. I added my variant for two-dimensional array (for second element in each inner element). Сan I apply your solution in some way or other for 2 dimensional array? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @user3679891, yes you can use this new function for tow-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Only I replace ...if(isset(end($result)[1]) && $key == end($result)[1])... by ...if(isset($result[count($result)-1][1]) && $key == $result[count($result)-1][1])...

Comment: Ok, so if this code solved your peoblem, please select this as Answer to close the post. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
$arr = array('cat','cat','cat','cat','dog','cat','cat','apple','mouse');
$final_arr = array(); $limit = count($arr);
$temp = array_values(array_filter(array_map(function($v){if($v != 'cat') return $v;}, $arr)));
for($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < $limit; $i++){
    if(isset($temp[$j])){
        $final_arr[] = 'cat';
        $final_arr[] = $temp[$j];
        $i++; $j++;
    }else{
        $final_arr[] = 'cat';
    }
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($final_arr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => cat
    [1] => dog
    [2] => cat
    [3] => apple
    [4] => cat
    [5] => mouse
    [6] => cat
    [7] => cat
    [8] => cat
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I have many 'cat' and 'dog'. I will try use something like IN operator. My tasks is (num start with 1 to readable) elem1 and elem2 will be different, elem3 and elem4 will be different and so on. Now I trying do it using for in for.

Comment: Updated my post. Hope it will help you!